# Variable declaration in c++

Tags: c++

when i run the following c++ code

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
   {
       cout<<i<<endl;
   }
   cout<<i;

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

I get result from no. 1 to 11.

i don't understand why the value of i = 11 after the block of for loop is finished,Please give me the reason.I have declared i inside for loop and scope of i has been finished after loop so why i get the outpout i=11 after execute second cout statement .I have not declared i in the variable declaration inside main.My question is that is i is visible outside of for loop?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems very odd to me. Your program shouldn't be compiling. `i` shouldn't exist after the loop is done.

Comment: I think @Omnifarious comment is better answer than the answers posted here!

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I think turbo c compiler :) seeing the getch() :P

Comment: @niko: Oh, **that** would explain it. That is a very, very old compiler. Now I understand. I had forgotten about the bios `getch` function on the old MS-DOS platform. That's 20 years old now! I can't believe anybody even still has the disks (and they'd have to be disks!) for it!

Comment: i think you are not getting my question i have edit it plz check it.

Comment: @arpit: That statement should not even have compiled, much less caused the output of '11'. On any modern C++ compiler I know of that code would result in an error. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @arpit: I tried to change my answer to more directly address what seems to be your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple reasons, this program does not compile. You are either using an extremely old compiler, an extremely permissive compiler, or not showing us the program you're actually having a problem with.

From your comments it seems that you actually can compile it. I can only guess that you are using a very old compiler. Perhaps an old MS-DOS compiler (Zortech C++? Turbo C++?) since the `getch` function is not generally a standard library function and doesn't do the right thing in the curses library anyway. It's probably an old BIOS-based function from the MS-DOS days.

The standard was changed awhile ago (over 10 years now) so that variable declarations in the parenthesized section of a for loop are local to that loop. It was once not actually the case that this was true.

I no longer have access to any compiler that's so old it doesn't handle things this way. I'm surprised anybody does. Your program will not compile on my compiler.

Here is a version of your program that does compile, even though it requires the `-lcurses` option to link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

using ::std::cout;
using ::std::endl;

int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)    
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the offending `cout << i;` statement is gone? That because it will not compile on a modern compiler.

Now, lets edit your program some more so it will compile with the `cout << i;` statement you're vexed about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    using ::std::cout;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }
    cout << "last: " << i << '\n';

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This, of course, does print out `last: 11` at the very end. This happens for a very obvious reason. What value does `i` have to have in order for the `i <= 10` test to fail? Why, any value greater than 10! And since `i` is having one added to it every loop iteration, the first value `i` has that has the property of being greater than 10 is 11.

The loop test happens at the top of the loop and is used to decide if the remainder of the loop should be executed or not. And the increment happens at the very bottom of the loop (despite appearing in the body of the `for` statement). So `i` will be 10, will be printed, and then 1 will be added to it. Then the loop test (`i <= 10`) will be done, it will be discovered that 11 <= 10 is false, and control will drop out of the loop down to the print statement after the loop, and `last: 11` will be printed.

And yes, the exact same thing will happen in C.

Comment: Typed mine up at the same time, but was slower.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Because the loop breaks when the condition `i<=10` becomes *untrue*, and this can happen when `i` becomes `11`. Simple!

I think you wanted to write `i < 10` .

Also, as @Omnifarious  noted in the comment, the code shouldn't even compile, as `i` doesn't exist outside the loop. Maybe, you've declared `i` outside the loop, in your original code?

Comment: @ Nawaz, he is not asking that. Outside of the for loop block there's one more cout for i, why that value is also displaying 11 as it is not declared outside for block

Comment: @skk: It is not what he is asking. Also, I assumed that there is some typo in asking the question.

Comment: Didn't downvote.  No typos - old compiler.  See my answer (and Omnifarious's it seems).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that it shouldn't compile (because **i** doesn't exist outside the loop block).

The loop runs from 1 to 10, so it stops when **i** reaches 11 and the condition fails. So **i** is 11 in the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have an old compiler.

`cout<<i<<endl;` should not compile, as `cout` and `endl` need to be qualified by the `std` namespace.

Fixing that, `std::cout<<i;` shouldn't compile because your variable is loop-scoped, so shouldn't even be visible outside the loop.

Fixing that, here's your code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << i;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It should become more obvious why `11` is printed now.

When `i == 10`, the loop executes, increments `i`, and checks its value.  It is then equal to `11`, so it exits the loop.

Then you have another print statement, that will print the post-loop value, which is `11`.

Here's the output I get from that corrected program:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   11

This is the same as you are getting.

If you only want to print `1-10`, then why have the extra `std::cout << i;`?

**Recommendation**

- Get an up to date C++ compiler that will give you syntax errors on things that are no longer valid in standard-compliant C++
- Get rid of the extra `std::cout << i;`
- Keep your `i` variable loop-scoped, as in your original code

The result from my recommendations will be that you only see `1` through `10` printed, and you will have slightly fewer unexpected surprises in the future (as some "bad" and surprising code won't even compile).

Comment: BTW, `conio.h` might be a windows header.  Not sure.  `getch` looks like it is from the curses library (?)

Comment: +1 - This is a very complete explanation. But I always clean up code to remove the stupid and useless `endl` statement. It should never have been put in the `iostream` library in the first place. It's a horrible waste and the cause of much mysteriously slow code and weird misconceptions about the portability of `'\n'`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122986/why-does-endl-get-used-as-a-synonym-for-n-even-though-it-incurs-significant-p

Comment: @Omnifarious: Thanks for the links.  Good reads, that direction :)